# Why not 'somewhy'?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

For [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/48769/8712), a desire for concision motivated me originally to use 'somewhy' instead of 'for some reason'; afterwards, a user kindly advised that 'somewhy' obsolesced. Why?

Google introduced me to http://somewhy.com/, whose author delineates his confusion of the absence and his reasoning justifying 'somewhy' (identical to mine). Though his questions have not been answered and
" *"Somewhy" didn't appear in the dictionaries I [he] checked* "
,
OED's entry does not answer our questions either:

> [somewhy](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/184495?redirectedFrom=somewhy) {adv.} = {rare.} 
>     For some reason or reasons.

Postscript: I read this [Wikipedia page on pro-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form), which displays the correlatives for 'why', but doesn't explain their obscurity. The lone prevalent exception is 'therefore'.

Comment: Somehow (and somewhy) it just never caught on. Maybe not enough somewhos liked the way it sounds. I don't know why—nor do I know whether somewho else would. Maybe they'll show up somewhen, if not now.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock *Somewho* use *somewhen*, but I don't know *somewhich*.

Comment: This question is awesome :)  Also this gives me an idea for a folk etymology for Summer: Somehere :)

Comment: And *anywhy* and *anywhen* and *somewhen* and... And [*anyone lived in a pretty how town...*](http://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/anyone-lived-pretty-how-town)

Comment: The reason that it can’t be found in most dictionaries (e.g. Merriam Webster or OOD) might be that it is used scarcely. As “Ask the editor” video (http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/index.php) at Merriam Webster’s website explains, it takes a lot of documented usage (many citations, from various sources, over a period of time) for a word to make it into a dictionary. So the word has to be used extensively to become a new dictionary entry, and as Brian pointed out this is just not the case with “somewhy” (yet). @LawArea51Proposal - I hope that this is better :-)

Comment: @Lucky Thank you! Yes. I upvoted your comment. I deeply apologise for any offense caused; I hope you won't mind my request. I look forward to your contributions!

Answer (score 3):

Simply because language does not work that way, and most of it is arbitrary. Forms fall into disuse and new borrowings enter the language all the time.