# Why is "elsewhen" not a proper word?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Elsewhere is an amazing word, as you can refer to other places very easily. What about *elsewhen*? Does such an equivalent of elsewhere for *time*  exist? For example:

> "Fertility might have fallen among women born between 1940 and 1960, and remained unchanged *elsewhen*."

Would that be an example of an appropriate use of that word, if it were to exist? If not, is there an alternative, easier way to say elsewhen, so that its existence has been unnecessary?

Comment: _"Is there an alternative, easier way to say that...?"_  Not that I can think of. _"Would that be ... an appropriate use of that word, if it were to exist?"_ I'd say it would.

Comment: "At other times"...

Comment: There are three dimensions of space but only one of time, so while _elsewhere_ implies arbitrarily distinct spatial locations, with time there are only a few possible distinctions. "Before and since" would work in addition to "at other times" as previously mentioned. In that example "otherwise remained unchanged throughout history" might be a good option too.

Comment: If you say something remained unchanged, that usually specifies a time or event, so wouldn't you just say "since"?

Comment: In any event, I like the word "elsewhen" and someone needs to start a campaign to get it back on the books :-)

Comment: Why isn't there a word for words that don't exist yet?

Comment: Who says elsewhen is not a proper word?  I've certainly seen it used, e.g. in SF stories dealing with time travel.

Comment: @jamesqf It's probably not cromulent, but as an SF type who's partial to word-coining, I use *elsewhen* in speech myself.

Comment: @Spratty The "books" are just compendiums of generalizations based on usage examples. So just start using it!

Comment: One can ask the same for 'somewhy': http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237572/50720 may pertain.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard "elsewhen" used.  If someone had asked me, I would have just said "sure, that's a word"

Comment: @Tony: There is such a word. It just doesn't exist yet. ;-)

Comment: *somewhen*, *everywhen*, *nowhen*, *elsewhen* - no problem.

Comment: @sumelic The alternative that popped into mind for me was "since then", due to the phrasing "remained unchanged" - it seems to indicate only after 1960, where "at other times" would include before 1940

Comment: @Drew elseproblem, someproblem, everyproblem. noproblem ;)

Comment: I think the reason this has fallen out of usage is because the one-way ordering of time is much more fundamental than the ordering of space. Elsewhere can mean to the left right, above, below etc. which will frequently be immaterial.  But to say elsewhen is ambiguous as to before or after, which is to be indifferent to something fundamental to cause, effect and meaning.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

*Elsewhen* did exist in English; the OED has several entries, the most recent from 1570, the earliest from 1418:

> Or ellys whan quan hem lest to remeve þens.

There are also entries for *elsehow*, *elsewhat*, *elsewhence*, *elsewhither*, and *elsewho*, plus *elsewards* and *elsewise*, and like *elsewhen*, all are marked as obsolete. The location-related words seem to have survived the longest, with *elsewhence* and *elsewhither* persisting into the 19th century and regionally, and of course *elsewhere* remaining in common usage.

*Why* those words fell out of fashion is hard to say, of course. Perhaps English speakers had more use for words for other locations than for other times— in the same way, we have *anywhere* and *everywhere*, but *anywhen* and *everywhen* are at best non-standard. On the other hand, we also lost *otherwhere*, except in some dialects, perhaps those which still use *otherwhat* and *othersome* and *otherward*; the OED doesn't specify.

In the situation you propose, the only single word I would have applied is ***otherwise***, a highly flexible word that simply means in some additional or different way— another time, another place, another manner. Or, you could always be explicit and say *at other times* or *in other years* or *other than this period*.

Comment: what does that quote say?

Comment: @luchonacho It is from a [line in a will](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/EEWills/1:22?rgn=div1;view=fulltext) that stipulates that decedent's widow will be cared for with her parents at Hardington, but if her father does not wish to be there, *or at some time wants to move elsewhere*, they will be supported by rents out of the same.

Comment: Your last paragraph suggests an answer to the implicit question in your penultimate paragraph; perhaps the non-location words fell out of fashion precisely because *otherwise* is so flexible, and context is usually sufficient to distinguish between various possible meanings.

Comment: @Kyle So why don't we use "everywise" to replace everywhere, everyone…

Comment: @PierreArlaud I don't think context is typically as helpful with "every-(x)" as with "other-(x)." The latter is the converse of something *already specified*, whereas the former must be able to work as a subject on its own.

Comment: @PierreArlaud: We do, it's spelled *always*

Comment: So ... "*elsewhen*" existed elsewhen?

Comment: @luchonacho:  Literally it translates: *"Or else when when they wish to remove thence"*.  The "else when" would be "if there should be an occasion" in Modern.

Comment: I trust you that the OED has the entry. However, the quote you gave isn't "elsewhen", but "else when", which are two separate words that anyone could use next to each other today. "I'll do X when y happens, or else when z happens."

Comment: Wait, really, *elsewise* is obsolete?

Comment: @T.E.D.: Many compounds can be written either with or without a space, and in many cases the space has become less common over time. What matters is whether the quotation is using it in the right sense of "elsewhen", not whether it writes it without a space.

Comment: @ruakh - My Middle English (?) isn't good enough to tell for sure, but it looks to me like a simple "else when".

Answer (score 27):

There actually is, or perhaps better said was, such a word in the adverb *othertimes*.  However, the OED says that *othertimes* is now obsolete. It was not uncommon in Early Modern English up through the 18th century, but its use declined during the first half of 19th century.  It tends to oppose *sometimes*.

- Democritus would **sometimes** say that the images and their circuitions were Gods, and **othertimes** this Nature, which disperseth these images, and then our knowledge and intelligence. (*Essays of Michael Lord of Montaigne)*
- The first appearances were, a low state of health, depressed, exhausted, and sallow look — the eyes sunken, **sometimes** of glossy whiteness, **othertimes** icteric, with dark areolae around — nose pinched — mouth blanched — except where ... (*Researches on Primary Pathology: And the Origin and Laws of Epidemics*)
- As often as the Devil appeared to the Mexicans, they made immediately an idol of the figure in which they bad seen him ; **sometimes** as a lion, **othertimes** as a dog, othertimes as a serpent ; and as the ambitious Devil took advantage of this ... (*The Poetical Works of Robert Southey*)

This adverb eventually came to be used as a noun serving as a prepositional object for *in* and *at*, and finally people gave up and wrote a space between the two words:

- at other times
- in other times

Which is where we stand today. People may well ask “why” something did or did not happen in language, but most such questions have no possible concrete answer.

The historical record shows many combinations with *any, other, some, when, time, times* that are now rarely seen. Combining the old ones with the extant ones, and disregarding hyphens, the list of such adverbs is very long:

> aforetime, anyplace, anyway, anyways, anywhen, anywhence, anywhere,
>   anywhither, anywise, beforetime, betimes, daytimes, elsehow, elsewards,
>   elsewhat, elsewhen, elsewhence, elsewhere, elsewhither, elsewho, elsewise,
>   everywhen, foretime, heretoforetime, midtime, mostwhen, noontimes, nowhen,
>   oftentime, oftentimes, otherlike, otherliker, othertime, othertimes,
>   otherward, otherwards, otherways, otherwhat, otherwhence, otherwhere,
>   otherwheres, otherwhile, otherwhiles, otherwhither, otherwise, overtime,
>   sometime, sometimes, someway, someways, somewhat, somewhatly, somewhen,
>   somewhence, somewhere, somewhile, somewhiles, somewhither, somewho,
>   somewhy, somewise, toforetime.

Comment: Is it possible that the word *othertimes* isn't actually obsolete as such, but the more common realization thereof is now *other times* (i.e. two separate words with a space between?-- For example, it does sound rather marked/poetic, but consider *Sometimes I feel like a nut; other times I don't*.

Comment: @errantlinguist I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: (Also, [sometimes I don't](https://youtu.be/QeibzLZn2hU))

Comment: Your last box has some amazing words!! `elsewhat`, `otherwhere`, `everywhen`. I'll try to implement some of them oftentimes in my lexicon.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an alternative, easier way to say that, so that its existence has been unnecessary?

"Easier" is somewhat subjective. It could be about brevity or clarity. You know, the interrogative words also have another modifier *-ever*, which has survived to modern times. This pairs nicely with the stand-alone word *else*:

- Whoever else
- Whatever else
- Whenever else
- Wherever else
- Why ever else (Note: *Whyever* used to be an accepted spelling, but it has mostly died off.)
- However else

In your example sentence, it would work fine with a slight reordering:

> Fertility might have fallen among women born between 1940 and 1960, and **whenever else** remained unchanged.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the OP's question about the word 'elsewhen'.

Comment: @Mitch OP asked "Is there an alternative, easier way to say that, so that its existence has been unnecessary?" Also, "why" answers are often impossible to prove, but in this case it is possible that elsewhen was viewed as short hand of "whenever else", and "whenever else" eventually won out over the years.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure I follow the reasoning but I'm sure that makes the connection more explicit. Can you edit you answer to add that?

Comment: @Mitch I added a little bit without leaning too speculative.

Comment: OK. Now I understand what you're trying to say. I just don't agree that 'whenever else' fits in that spot with the intended meaning.