# Why aren't "nohow" and "nowhy" real words?

Tags: word-usage

So we have:

- Where-Nowhere
- When-Never(/Nowhen)
- Who-Nobody
- What-Nothing

Why can't we also have "nohow" and "nowhy"?

"No reason" works to some extent, but "nohow" isn't really replaceable in a concise manner, to my knowledge.

The real question here is not how to say it otherwise, but why it would be horribly wrong to use it. And would it?

Comment: Of potentially related interest: *[Why is “elsewhen” not a proper word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370383)*

Comment: Candidate words accepted into the lexus have to jump certain hurdles before wordness is accepted by most. One is clarity of meaning; one is being used and understood correctly by a reasonable number of Anglophones. 'Why' hereabouts (assuming your assertion is correct) probably has no better answer than 'that's the way Anglophones vote'.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard "nohow" but have not heard "nowhen".  My dictionary has "nohow", with two meanings, one labeled "US" the other labeled "archaic"

> **nohow** ADVERB
>   1 (US) Used, especially in uneducated speech, to emphasize a negative.
>   ‘they never executes nobody nohow’
>
> 2 (archaic) Not attractive, well, or in good order.
>   [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nohow)

The answer to "why are they not real words?" is they have been used rarely or never.  But if you like "nowhy", go ahead and use it yourself.  Maybe it will catch on!

---

Think of "nohow" as a negative form of "anyhow".  In fact I think all of your words are like that:

- Anywhre-Nowhere
- *Anywhen-Nowhen
- Anybody-Nobody
- Anything-Nothing
- Anyhow-Nohow

---

I said I have not seen "nowhen".  Well, maybe I have seen it (along with "anywhen") in time-travel science fiction.

Comment: In _Through the Looking-Glass_, Lewis Carroll has Tweedledum say 'Wax-works weren't made to be looked at for nothing, nohow!' But I don't think I've ever come across _nowhen_.

Comment: "Nobody can see the Great Oz.  Not nobody, not nohow!"

Comment: Ha ha, whenever I have said uneducated speech around here, everyone jumps on the PC wagon. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble upon "nowhy" in *The House by the Churchyard* by J. Sheridan LeFanu (1863):

> ‘You must not talk that way, Devereux,’ [Puddock] said, still a good deal more dismayed by his looks than his words. ‘Why are you so troubled with vapours and blue devils?’
>
> ‘Nowhy!’ said Devereux, with a grim smile.

Comment: Hello, Jens. Nice find, but 'One swallow ....'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/426780)